# Selenium Grid+TestNG+Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, testng, selenium-grid

I need organize functional testing of my application. I need use selenium grid + testng + webdriver. As I found the good way to set project is using maven in eclipse. I have setup selenium grid, but don't know how appropriatelly setup the maven project which will work with all those tools. Maybe someone have experience in it or usefull links. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use testng tests with maven you will need to set up maven surefire plugin to launch your tests suites defined in testng.

First, you need to have testng in your dependencies, so add this to your pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
  [...]
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  [...]
</dependencies>
```

Then you need to tell surefire which test suite is being used, let`s suppose it is suite.xml:

```
<plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

As I can see, you are using grid, so if you want to run them in parallel, you can do the following in the plugin section of your pom.xml file:

```
</plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>methods</parallel>
          <threadCount>10</threadCount>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

Of course you will need to have selenium hub running on that pc and at least one client.
Make sure your tests are configured to run using selenium grid2 instead of local webdriver.

Regards,

Santiago